# Spock: creating mocked objects at run-time

Tags: java, mocking, spock

I have a class `Foo` that has a method `Bar makeBar(String id)`. As you can guess, `makeBar` creates a new `Bar` object with the id `id`. `Bar` has a getter for `id`.

For the purpose of my test I need to mock `Foo`. I would like the mocked `makeBar` method to create mocked `Bar` objects for which the getter returns the correct `id` (the one that was given to `makeBar`).

---

So to be clear, I want to create a mocked instance `foo` of `Foo` such that

```
foo.makeBar(someId)
```

returns a mocked `Bar` object `bar` for which

```
bar.getId() == someID
```

Is there a way to do this with Spock, or should I stub everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have a mock return other mocks. This will do the trick:

```
Foo foo = Mock()

foo.makeBar(_) >> { String id ->
    Bar bar = Mock()
    bar.getId() >> id
    bar
}
```

I've published the complete and runnable code here: http://webconsole.spockframework.org/?id=40001.

Comment: Thanks! This saves me 100+ lines of stubs :)